# Text written by tinnymce is not displayed well formatted in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I use Tinymce to edit article body in my asp.net mvc application. I also put [ValidateInput(false)] on 'Edit' Action result, and I get no errors, but When I want to show the article body to user, even by using Html.Raw(article.Body), it show raw html tags and not the formaytted text. Here is a example of out put:

```
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>dsadad asdsadad asdsadadad</strong></span></p>
```

ps: I use AntiXss library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AntiXss is encoding the HTML so `<` will become `&lt;`. To decode it back to HTML, try this:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(article.Body))
```